# handlebars: Pass dynamic variables to partials

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a partial that contains the common structure of my web page:

```
<script id="page-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    .....
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>{{title}}
                <small>
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> {{subtitle}}
                </small>
                {{/if}}
            </h1>
        </div>
        ......
    </div>
</script>
```

Then, from each page, I call the partial passing the attributes **title** and **subtitle**. It works fine with constants attributes, for instance:

```
{{#> page title="Customers" subtitle="List of customers"}}
  <!-- Page HTML -->
{{/page}}
```

However, it doesn't work when I try to pass a variable:

```
{{#> page title="Customer" subtitle="{{customer.name"}}
  <!-- Page HTML -->
{{/page}}
```

It displays {{customer.name}} instead of the real name of the customer. Is it possible to make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `{{#> page title="Customer" subtitle="{{customer.name"}}` is very likely a syntax error. Check your code sample.

Comment: Sorry, I only pasted the first line of the partial invocation

Comment: Just found da duplicate of that question. Does that work for you?

Comment: I don't think is the same response. In your duplicated response they just pass constants values, no the variable itself.

Answer (score 6):

I finally managed to make this work. I let the response here just in case it could benefit someone else:

```
{{#> page title="Customer" subtitle=customer.name
   <!-- Page HTML -->
{{/page}}
```

It was only needed to remove {{}} and "". Notice that **customer** is the name of a variable available in the template.